# Changing CommandTimeout for nHibernate Session

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

How to change command Timeout for a session in nHibernate. I know it can be done in App.Config   but I want to increase the default value only for one business operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do this session-wide, but you can control timeouts for both individual [IQuery](http://mausch.github.com/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/196bf46d-0aae-6bd1-be90-6ec3692ed171.htm) and [ICriteria](http://mausch.github.com/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/e59a3754-a06b-0ac9-6020-bae252418160.htm) with SetTimeout().